# How can I add a timestamp to a cron job output?

Tags: cron, timestamp

I have a `crontab` job set up which records the speed of my network every two minutes:

```
*/2 * * * * /usr/local/bin/speedtest >> ~/Documents/speedtest.log
```

The output is saved to `speedtest.log`:

```
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 60.10 Mbit/s
```

Is there a way to add a timestamp (the format given is an example only; the actual format is irrelevant) to each entry to achieve something like this?

```
20200125221000: Testing download speed................................................................
20200125221042: Download: 60.10 Mbit/s
```

If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
*/2 * * * * echo "$(/usr/local/bin/speedtest) $(date)" >> ~/Documents/speedtest.log
```